# Make conjunction a synonym of conjunctions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

What about making [conjunction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunction) a synonym of [conjunctions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunctions)? Since only one question is tagged [conjunction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunction) it might suffice to retag that one question but it would be more future proof to make synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proposed [conjunction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunction) as synonym of [conjunctions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunctions); if four users vote it, the tag will become synonym of the tag.

Comment: [It's already a synonym.](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/conjunctions/synonyms)